# Inverse of a differentiable function equal to its derivative then f is analytic

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, analyticity

I've found a nice problem concerning analytic functions. Here it is:

Let $f: (0, \infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a  function differentiable on $(0, \infty)$ and such that $f^{-1} = f'$. Prove that $f$ is analytic on $(0, \infty)$.

I'm not sure if it's relevant, but I know that $f$ cannot be a bijection :)

Could you help me?

Comment: is $f$ infinitely differentiable? this is essentially what the question appears to be asking

Comment: @DanZimm: Analyticity is stronger than infinite differentiability.

Comment: Just to confirm - is $f^{-1}$ actually the *inverse function* s.t. $f\circ f^{-1} \equiv \iota$? (Then we assume $f$ injective.) If so, does $f^{-1} = f'$ require that the domains of both sides are the same (in which case the image of $f$ is $(0,\infty)$ as well), or that they agree on their domains (so that $f'(-1)$ is ignored if $f(x)=-1$ for some $x$), or what?

Comment: @JonasMeyer ah right right, my bad

Comment: Yes, $f^{-1}$ is the inverse function of $f$. I think we can assume that they agree on their domains. Actually, I've rewritten the whole problem.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/279517/does-there-exist-f0-infty-to0-infty-such-that-f-f-1 and http://mathoverflow.net/questions/34052/function-satisfying-f-1-f/ for the same setup, though they ask different questions.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is affirmative, as proven in [this](https://mathoverflow.net/a/256811/104577) MathOverflow post. The answerer, José Hdz. Stgo., assumes $f:[0,\infty) \to [0, \infty)$ and $f(0) = 0$, but these additional hypotheses don't affect the argument regarding analyticity.