# Inverse of a function equal to its derivative

Tags: functions

> I have found  that the function
>
> $$f(x) = \left(\frac{1}{2}
>  \left(\sqrt{5}+1\right)\right)^{\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}}
>  x^{\frac{\sqrt{5}+1}{2} }$$
>
> satisfies the relation $$f^{-1}(x)=f'(x)$$

Is this solution unique? If so, how to prove it?

Comment: This has been asked and answered before: https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24f%5E%7B-1%7D(x)%3Df%27(x)%24

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/279332, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/735695. https://math.stackexchange.com/q/279517, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1916191

Comment: @MartinR Thank you! I searched MSE but couldn't find anything

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rNUfiQgj6ZI&list=LL&index=124&t=1s

Comment: Also with Dr Peyam: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0IlWyIaMXqI